# how to guide the user on how to use the application in android with our custom views

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to show the instructions to the user while using our application. I can able to achieve the same by using showcase view library. But the problem is, while using that library by default "ok" button will come which I don't want to show. And I want to show the arrow image which is there in the image attached below. Can anyone help me to finish my task.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yj4U.png)

Comment: do you mean guideline while app started?